# Exception that terminate batch but without rollback

Tags: spring-batch

I need to insert a record into a table and then have the batch terminate with an exception without causing the insert to be rolled back.

I have used  but it does not terminate the batch

Comment: `I have used but it does not terminate the batch`: Can you share what have you used?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fault tolerant step and set the exceptions that should not cause a rollback using [FaultTolerantStepBuilder#noRollback](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/step/builder/FaultTolerantStepBuilder.html#noRollback-java.lang.Class-).

Then you can use a listener (`ItemProcessListener` or `ItemWriteListener` depending on where the exception is thrown) to intercept the exception and terminate the step (and its surrounding job) with [StepExecution#setTerminateOnly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/StepExecution.html#setTerminateOnly--).

Answer (score 0):

I have used this:

```
<batch:step id="id">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="reader" processor="processor" writer="writer" commit-interval="1">
            </batch:chunk>
            <batch:no-rollback-exception-classes>
                 <batch:include class="com.exception.myException"></batch:include>
            </batch:no-rollback-exception-classes>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
```

it allows only to avoid rollback but not terminate batch. I want terminate batch after the execution of myException.

The myException is launched in processor